# Selecting random periods by date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For each id in my dataframe, I want to sample rows between a random date range period (can be 1, 2, 4 weeks) that is inside the min and max dates of that given id. For example, for given id I have data between `2022-09-01` and `2022-09-28` I want to sample random 7 days which would give me all records between a random start and end date like `2022-09-06` and `2022-09-12`.

One idea I have is just randomly sampling a start_date and then adding my desired interval on top of it to find end_date, check if it is a viable end_date if not repeat the first start_date sampling if it is viable then filter the data based on that range, but with this approach I am missing out on a lot of combinations and feel like there has to be a better way for this.

Example df:

```
data = [{'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-01 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-02 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-03 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-04 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-06 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-07 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-08 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-09 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-10 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-11 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-12 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-13 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-14 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-15 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-16 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-17 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-18 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-19 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-20 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-21 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-22 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-23 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-24 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-25 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-26 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-27 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-28 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-01 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-02 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-03 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-04 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-05 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-06 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-07 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-08 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-09 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-10 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-11 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-12 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-13 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-14 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-15 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-16 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-17 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-18 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-19 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-20 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-21 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-22 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-23 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-24 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-25 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-26 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-27 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-28 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-29 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-30 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-10-01 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-10-02 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-10-03 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-10-04 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-10-05 00:00:00')}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output example:

```
output_data = [{'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-06 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-07 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-08 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-09 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-10 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-11 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 1, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-12 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-15 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-16 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-17 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-18 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-19 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-20 00:00:00')},
 {'account_id': 2, 'date': Timestamp('2022-09-21 00:00:00')}]

output = pd.DataFrame(output_data)
```

Comment: Have you tried `df.groupby("account_id").sample(7)`?

Comment: Why do you feel "I am missing out on a lot of combinations"?

Comment: @Timus I want them to be consecutive/existing days in a date-range.

Comment: @Nick maybe I couldn't process it correctly in my thoughts, initially did not make sense to me but turns out it does make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here is one way you can do it:

Basically you groupby `account_id`, then create a `pd.date_range` of the group, starting at its minimum, ending at its maximum minus the interval of days (or anything else. For more information, read the documentation of [`pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html)) you chose, because you can't get random 7 increasing days if you start 2 days before the groups max.
`pd.date_range` returns a list with all possible dates you can start. From this list you pick one date using `random.choice` and pass it to another `pd.date_range` as start, together with period which is again the number of intervals you chose.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

num_of_days = 7 # or whatever interval you choose
out = (
    df
    .groupby('account_id')
    .apply(lambda grp: 
           pd.date_range(
               start = random.choice(
                   [*pd.date_range(
                       grp['date'].min(), 
                       grp['date'].max() - pd.DateOffset(days=num_of_days)
                   )
                   ]
               ), 
               periods = num_of_days)
          )
    .explode()
    .reset_index(name='random_consecutive_days')
)
print(out)
```

```
    account_id random_consecutive_days
0            1              2022-09-13
1            1              2022-09-14
2            1              2022-09-15
3            1              2022-09-16
4            1              2022-09-17
5            1              2022-09-18
6            1              2022-09-19
7            2              2022-09-20
8            2              2022-09-21
9            2              2022-09-22
10           2              2022-09-23
11           2              2022-09-24
12           2              2022-09-25
13           2              2022-09-26
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed. I like the simplicity of it as well, thank you!